# matlab: lsqcurvefit, only one upper bound

Tags: matlab, least-squares

simple question.. Is it possible to set only one upper bound for lsqcurvefit, without limiting others?

I need something like:

```
lb = [0 0 0];
ub = [~ ~ 5];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not putting this as an answer since I don't have time to test it ... but does specifying the limit as `+inf` work? That's how I used to do it using the `fit` function in the curve fitting toolbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help lsqcurvefit`:

> X = LSQCURVEFIT(FUN,X0,XDATA,YDATA,LB,UB) defines a set of lower and
>
> ```
> upper bounds on the design variables, X, so that the solution is in the
> range LB <= X <= UB. Use empty matrices for LB and UB if no bounds
> exist. Set LB(i) = -Inf if X(i) is unbounded below; set UB(i) = Inf if
> X(i) is unbounded above.
> ```

So yes, Dan Becker is right -- using

```
lb = [   0  0  0];
ub = [inf inf  5];
```

will do the trick.